# Incomplete dictionary listing built using functions and while loop

Tags: python, function, dictionary, while-loop

I have written a code to use a function and a while loop to use user input for populating a dictionary. Unfortunately, my code only seems to accept the last key:value pair entered by the user. What I was hoping for is to have multiple key:value pairs appear when I run the code.

I'm fairly new to Python and would appreciate have my misstep(s) highlighted. Thanks you.

ps: see code below

```
def make_album(artist_name,album_title):
    """Return a dictionary of information about album."""
    album_details_1 = {'name': artist_name, 'title': album_title}

    return album_details_1


while True:
    print("\nPlease tell me the name of your favourite artist:")

    art_name =input("artist name: ")         

    alb_title=input("album title: ")

    repeat = input("Would you like to enter another response? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        break



musician_1 = make_album(art_name, alb_title)


print(musician_1)
```

Comment: No, the intention was to keep the while loop outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you only get one key:value pair is because every time you run the loop you are overriding the variables. You could use a simple list to accumulate all musicians and print it at the end:

```py
def make_album(artist_name,album_title):
    """Return a dictionary of information about album."""
    album_details_1 = {'name': artist_name, 'title': album_title}

    return album_details_1

musicians = []  # list of musicians

while True:
    print("\nPlease tell me the name of your favorite artist:")

    art_name =input("artist name: ")         
    alb_title=input("album title: ")
    musicians.append(make_album(art_name, alb_title))  # add the new musicians to list

    repeat = input("Would you like to enter another response? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat.lower() == 'no':
        break


print(musicians)
```

Output:

```
Please tell me the name of your favorite artist:
artist name: 1
album title: 1
Would you like to enter another response? (yes/no) yes

Please tell me the name of your favorite artist:
artist name: 2
album title: 2
Would you like to enter another response? (yes/no) no
[{'name': '1', 'title': '1'}, {'name': '2', 'title': '2'}]
```

Note that I used `repeat.lower()` to check for the input, this way your program will stop independent of the string case (NO/No/nO/no).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fact that the while loop is asking the user to input an artist and album name every iteration, but it doesn't do anything with that information. It just asks the user over and over until they say no. Only then is a dictionary created from the last artist,album pair.

When you say you want multiple key value pairs, you already do.
If I run the program and enter artist name "freddy", and album "my_album", I get:

```
Please tell me the name of your favourite artist:
artist name: freddy
album title: my_album
Would you like to enter another response? (yes/no) no
{'title': 'my_album', 'name': 'freddy'}
```

Note that I have a key "title" with value "my_album" and a key "name" with value "freddy".  So there are 2 key,value pairs.

When you said you want multiple key value pairs, I assume you mean you want to keep track of multiple artist, album name pairs. If so, the best way to do this in Python would be to use a tuple. You could have `('freddy','my_album')` as a tuple.  Using a tuple, you don't have to have any keys. Instead, the position of each item tells you it's meaning. In this case, the first item of the tuple is the artist name, and the second item is the album name.

Then, using tuples, you can have a list of them to keep track of all artist, album pairs:

```
def make_album(artist_name,album_title):
  """Return a tuple of information about album."""
  return (artist_name, album_title)

all_tuples = []
while True:
  print("\nPlease tell me the name of your favourite artist:")

  art_name =input("artist name: ")

  alb_title=input("album title: ")

  musician = make_album(art_name, alb_title)
  all_tuples.append(musician)

  repeat = input("Would you like to enter another response? (yes/no) ")
  if repeat == 'no':
    break

print(all_tuples)
```

You don't even need a function to create the tuple: `musician = (art_name, alb_title)`

or, better yet, `all_tuples.append((art_name,alb_title))`